# WooCommerce update all variations (programmatically)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, e-commerce

I'm trying to update a custom field in WooCommerce under each variation within all products. I got the code to work for a simple product, but cannot loop through the variations and update them. I tried nearly every WooCommerce variations loop on Stackoverflow but all of them return errors or simply don't work. Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Current code in functions.php for simple products.

```
add_action('init', 'bulk_update_post_meta_data');
    function bulk_update_post_meta_data() {
        $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'suppress_filters' => true
        );

        $posts_array = get_posts( $args );

        foreach($posts_array as $post_array) {
        $Cogcost = get_post_meta( $post_array->ID, '_regular_price', true );

            update_post_meta($post_array->ID, '_wc_cog_cost', $Cogcost);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'init', 'bulk_update_post_meta_data' );

function bulk_update_post_meta_data() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'     => -1,
        'post_type'          => 'product_variation',
        'suppress_filters'   => true
    );

    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $posts_array as $post_array ) {
        $Cogcost = get_post_meta( $post_array->ID, '_regular_price', true );

        update_post_meta( $post_array->ID, '_wc_cog_cost', $Cogcost );
    }
}
```

This will get all variations.

Comment: Thanks you for the information, although this did not work I tried it on multiple fields and different sites too and it didn't update the variations.

Comment: Please check $posts_array has the values from the DB

Comment: I don't believe it has any values. The product_variation  post_type is a child of product so doesn't product have to be obtained first then product_variation?

Comment: @therealdeal variations are stored as product_variation in post type in wp_posts table

Comment: I was finally able to figure it out. I had a plugin overwriting the function I had so wasn't pulling data correct. After attempting it in a fresh install of WP it worked. Thank you for your help.